# JavaScript concatenate a variable into a constructor

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to concatenate a variable into a constructor in JavaScript

I have a variable like this:

```
var selectedLayer = "myLayer";
```

and then I am creating a **Leaflet tile layer**, I want to then incorporate the variable into the constructor:

```
test = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://localhost/geoserver/wms',{layers : 'geonode:<selectedLayer>', format: 'image/png'});
```

Comment: `... layers: 'geonode:' + selectedLayer, format: ...`

Comment: the issue I was facing was that I thought that I needed a trailing ' (quote) after the variable. I then learned that the JS compiler is converting my sting to include beginning and ending quotes for the concatonated string, so this works:

 test = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://localhost/geoserver/wms', {
    layers : 'geonode:'+selectedLayer,                                                          
    format: 'image/png'
    });

while I was trying : 'geonode:'+selectedLayer'... or 'geonode:'+selectedLayer+'... or 'geonode:'+selectedLayer+'+...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string concatenation in javascript is done with the simple `+`, so your case would be:

```
{
 layers: 'geonode:' + selectedLayer, 
 format: 'image/png'
}
```